# I got the error while sending mail using smtplib server in python program

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

Here is my code:

```
send: 'mail FROM:<zequbal20@gmail.com> size=453\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 OK m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 OK m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp
send: 'rcpt TO:<>\r\n'
reply: '555 5.5.2 Syntax error. m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (555); Msg: 5.5.2 Syntax error. m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp
send: 'rcpt TO:<>\r\n'
reply: '555 5.5.2 Syntax error. m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (555); Msg: 5.5.2 Syntax error. m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp
send: 'rset\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.5 Flushed m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 Flushed m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp
{"('mezequbal20@gmail.co',)": (555, '5.5.2 Syntax error. m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp'), "('mezequbal@gmail.com',)": (555, '5.5.2 Syntax error. m6sm1118977pfm.22 - gsmtp')}
```

Comment: def alertMail(sender,recipients,subject,body):      
       msg = MIMEMultipart()
       msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) #body = "YOUR MESSAGE HERE"
          msg['Subject'] = subject
       msg['From'] = sender #sender = 'me@example.com'
       msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients) 
       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
       server.ehlo()
       server.starttls()
       server.login(sender, "My Password")
       server.set_debuglevel(1) #1 is debug level
       server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
       server.quit()

Comment: post your python error..

Comment: There is an edit button under your question to allow you to make changes. This is better than including code as a comment.